# Avoiding fails from ArcObjects geoprocessing with .NET?

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing, .net

There are some nice features in ArcToolbox we can use, but for some reason, this is NOT working properly. It doesn't even throw me an error.

My software is running inside ArcMap, so no need to AoInitialize again, corret?

```
    public void Execute()
    {
        InitializeProduct();
        try
        {
            Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
            gp.OverwriteOutput = true;

            FeatureToPoint featureToPoint = new FeatureToPoint();

            string outputPathName = CurrentWorkspace.PathName + "\\teste_centroide";

            featureToPoint.in_features = InputFeatureClass;
            featureToPoint.out_feature_class = outputPathName;
            featureToPoint.point_location = "INSIDE";

            IGeoProcessorResult result = (IGeoProcessorResult)gp.Execute(featureToPoint, null);

            if (result == null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= gp.MessageCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(gp.GetMessage(i));
                }
            }

            IGPUtilities gpUtils = new GPUtilitiesClass();
            this.OutputFeatureClass = gpUtils.OpenFeatureClassFromString(outputPathName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\r\n");
        }
```

This is a code example I'm having here. I generated the DataManagement tools assembly, but I could not find the file to sign it.

This code just gives me an error. is it because of the signing?

I've tried the other way too, using IVariantArray and calling from the tool name, without sucess. Is it just me or...?

Can anyone point me a "nicer" solution? I need to run several process that are already built in ArcToolbox that I really don't want to duplicate.

Comment: What is the error you mention later in your question?

Comment: Hello Dandy. It doesnt throw errors, it just fails.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the code below, the multi2single function works for me in 10.0.  I couldn't test Feature2Point since I don't have an ArcInfo license, can you?.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void TestGP(IApplication app)
    {
        IMxDocument mxDoc = (IMxDocument)app.Document;
        //Feat2Point((IFeatureLayer)mxDoc.FocusMap.get_Layer(0), @"D:\Projects\AmberGIS\Forums\forumtest.gdb\f2p");
        Multi2Single((IFeatureLayer)mxDoc.FocusMap.get_Layer(0), @"D:\Projects\AmberGIS\Forums\forumtest.gdb\m2s");
    }

    public static void Multi2Single(IFeatureLayer inLayer, string outPath)
    {
        MultipartToSinglepart m2s = new MultipartToSinglepart();
        m2s.in_features = inLayer.FeatureClass;
        m2s.out_feature_class = outPath;
        Execute(m2s);
    }

    public static void Feat2Point(IFeatureLayer inLayer, string outPath)
    {
        FeatureToPoint f2p = new FeatureToPoint();
        f2p.in_features = inLayer.FeatureClass;
        f2p.out_feature_class = outPath;
        Execute(f2p);
    }

    public static void Execute(IGPProcess proc)
    {
        Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
        gp.AddOutputsToMap = true;
        gp.OverwriteOutput = true;
        gp.RegisterGeoProcessorEvents((IGeoProcessorEvents)new GPEvents());
        IGeoProcessorResult2 result = gp.Execute(proc, null) as IGeoProcessorResult2;
        IGPMessages msgs = result.GetResultMessages();
        for(int i=0;i<msgs.Count;i++)
            Debug.Print("{0} {1}", msgs.GetMessage(i).Description, msgs.GetMessage(i).Type);            
    }
}
public class GPEvents : IGeoProcessorEvents3, IGeoProcessorEvents 
{
    #region IGeoProcessorEvents3 Members
    public void OnProcessMessages(IGeoProcessorResult result, IGPMessages pMsgs)
    {
        Debug.Print("OnProcessMessages {0}", result.Status);
    }
    public void OnProgressMessage(IGeoProcessorResult result, string message)
    {
        Debug.Print("OnProgressMessages {0}", result.Status);
    }
    public void OnProgressPercentage(IGeoProcessorResult result, double percentage)
    {
        Debug.Print("OnProgressPercentage {0}", result.Status);
    }
    public void OnProgressShow(IGeoProcessorResult result, bool Show)
    {
        Debug.Print("OnProgressShow {0}", result.Status);
    }
    public void PostToolExecute(IGeoProcessorResult result)
    {
        Debug.Print("PostToolExecute {0}", result.Status);
    }
    public void PreToolExecute(IGeoProcessorResult result)
    {
        Debug.Print("PreToolExecute {0}",result.Status);
    }
    #endregion

    #region IGeoProcessorEvents Members

    void IGeoProcessorEvents.OnMessageAdded(IGPMessage message)
    {
        Debug.Print("OnMessageAdded {0} {1}", message.Description, message.Type);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IGeoProcessorEvents.PostToolExecute(IGPTool Tool, ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IArray Values, int result, IGPMessages Messages)
    {
        Debug.Print("PostToolExecute2 {0}", Tool.Name);
    }

    void IGeoProcessorEvents.PreToolExecute(IGPTool Tool, ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IArray Values, int processID)
    {
        if (Tool.IsLicensed())
            Debug.Print("PreToolExecute");
        else
            Debug.Print("tool is not licensed to run");
    }

    void IGeoProcessorEvents.ToolboxChange()
    {
        Debug.Print("ToolboxChange");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I get this output in VS:

```
PreToolExecute
PostToolExecute2 MultipartToSinglepart
Executing: MultipartToSinglepart GPL0 D:\Projects\AmberGIS\Forums\forumtest.gdb\m2s esriGPMessageTypeProcessDefinition
Start Time: Thu Sep 02 11:32:44 2010 esriGPMessageTypeProcessStart
Succeeded at Thu Sep 02 11:32:51 2010 (Elapsed Time: 7.00 seconds) esriGPMessageTypeProcessStop
```

Comment: That error handling is fantastic Kirk.  I never spent enough time using the geoprocessor to know about the IGeoProcessorEvent interfaces.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: YOUR code works! ArcObjects does not like me.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct in that there's no need for AoInitialize.
As you've discovered, debugging with the geo-processor object is a pain in the neck.

What you need to do so read the message, warning and error queue's after each call, to check for problems.  There's no such luck as relying on the standard .NET error handing.

Try this after each execute call (note the GetMessageS, not GetMessage)...

```
Console.WriteLine("Messages: " + gp.GetMessages(1));
Console.WriteLine("Warnings: " + gp.GetMessages(2));
Console.WriteLine("Errors: " + gp.GetMessages(3));
```

Comment: Hello eldac! I gave up after a few hours of head-banging, but I will try this again soon and I'll finish up the follow ups on the question.

Could this be a problem with signing the assembly when you first generate it?

Comment: Hi George, it's probably not a signing issue.  If you have a simple syntax/path/type error in the params for the FeatureToPoint (or any other geoprocessing tool), it will fail without any notification, hence the inspection of the error queue's.  I hardly bother with the geoprocessing tools anymore.  It just takes so long to get it working in most cases, as debugging is hell.

Comment: This is a pain, because I need to test a centroid, but I'm not sure how could I link the alterations I need to make without using a geoprocessing tool. I need to alter a polygon layer, but the testing needs to be done under it's centroid. I'm using a spatial query to filter my results, so I would loose that.