# Converting multipart polygon to singlepart in ArcObjects with C#?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#

I have a multipart feature and I need to convert it to a singlepart feature.

Couldn't find any code sample.

I wonder if i could get some help from you?

I'm working with ArcGIS 10 and c#.

Comment: How do you want to handle islands (interior rings)?

Comment: Curious if there a non-GP way to do this in ArcObjects?

Comment: You can do this w/o the GP. Cast the feature's shape to IGeometryCollection and then check the GeometryCount property to see if it is a multipart feature. Then you will need to create a new feature class to write each part to. Loop the feauture's individual parts using IEnumGeometry and IGeometryBag.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS has a tool: "Multipart to SinglePart".

---

This can be called with **Python** or **JScript**:

`import arcgisscripting //not needed for JScript`

`gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx")`

`gp.MultipartToSinglepart_management("", Output_Feature_Class)`

---

Alternately **VBScript**:

`gp.AddToolbox "C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx"`

`gp.MultipartToSinglepart_management "", Output_Feature_Class`

Not sure how to do it with C#, but I guess you could call one of those languages with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Geoprocessor object to access geoprocessing tools (in this case [MultipartToSinglepart](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003r000000)).

Here's a [Getting started article](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0410/gpandnet.html) about using Geoprocessor.

Comment: I just solved my problem using the following code. It works exactly the way a need.
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/issues-with-geoprocessing-with-net